# OS X take full page screenshot not in web browser?

Tags: objective-c, macos, screenshot

I need to realize a screenshot of full page in OS X not only in web browser, and the app is not limit with sandbox. I have googled a lot, but really have no ideas, hope someone who can give me a hint. Really thanks.

********************update my question*********************************

I have realized the screenshot of any window on screen, what I need to realize is like screenshot of full page in chrome, it can grab the whole page even the part is not shown.

But the challenge is I should grab not only in web browser, also any window who have a scrollview. Like:

- Window is like the picture below, the window can not show all apps.
  [image]
- What I need grab is like:
  [image]

Hope I expressed clearly and there will be somebody give me some hints, thanks~

Comment: What do you mean full page? You mean SC if your App's full screen or somewhere else in mac?

Comment: Anyways you should check Apple's [Son of Grab](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: @NSNoob really thanks, I have run the Son of Grab. I think I did not express clearly, I will update my question, thanks.

Comment: Ah yup it is evidently clear now what you are asking so I have removed my downvote. Sadly I do not know how can that be achieved. Hope someone who does finds your question

Comment: @NSNoob hah,thanks all the same~